# .net xml serialization, possible to apply some formatting?

Tags: .net, serialization

I use a lot of XML serialization in one app I am busy with. .Net by default just shoves everything on 1 line.

Is it not possible to get some formatting order during the serialization. Would like to have it neater, because at times people have to open these xml files up and read them.

I guess what would be awesome is to have correct indentation and line breaks.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your XmlTextWriter object, set the `Formatting` to `Formatting.Indented`, and set the `Indentation` property to the number of spaces to indent each level.